# Change item of Datagridviewcombobox programmatically VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

```
Dim cListItems As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Combobox_values)
                If ds.Tables("items_prices").Rows(0).Item("item_selldozen") > 0 Then
                    Dim item_selldozen As String = ds.Tables("items_prices").Rows(0).Item("item_selldozen")
                    cListItems.Add(New Combobox_values("Dozen", item_selldozen))
                End If

                Dim dgvcbc As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = DirectCast(CType(main.ActiveMdiChild, discount_new_discount).discountitems_new_discount.Rows(last_row).Cells(3), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
                dgvcbc.DataSource = cListItems 'Fill cListItems
                dgvcbc.DisplayMember = "Text"
                dgvcbc.ValueMember = "Value"
```

All i need to do is add a Handler for combobox to select the first of the values ​​filled.

Anybody have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value using the first item from the source.

```
dgvcbc.Value = cListItems(0)
```